# Exercise about defining "same level" in Conceptual Mathematics

Tags: physics

Near the start of Lawvere and Schanuel's *Conceptual Mathematics* they ask:

> The part of Galileo’s work which we discussed is really concerned with
> only a small portion of space, say the immediate neighbourhood of the
> tower of Pisa. Since the ground might be uneven, what could be meant
> by saying that two points are at the same level? Try to describe an
> experiment for deciding whether two nearby points are at the same
> level, without using ‘height’ (distance from an imaginary plane of
> reference.) Try to use the most elementary tools possible.

I can think of putting a spirit level between the two points, or putting a smooth plank between them and seeing if a ball at one point will roll to the other or *vice versa*. Or putting an altimeter (i.e. a barometer) at both points and seeing if the air pressure is the same. But from the last sentence, I think the authors had something else in mind. Does anyone know what the "correct" answer is?

Edit: The best answer I can think of is to hang a plumb line at each point, and see if they form a right angle with the line joining the points.

Comment: A straight plank with the rolling balls seems like a good answer to me. Ultimately, though, this is a physics question and not really about mathematics.

Comment: Drop two objects from the points and see if they take the same amount of time to hit the ground.

Comment: @MarkSaving The question may not be strictly about mathematics but it comes from the book "Conceptual Mathematics" which is a book that is strictly about mathematics. As an aside, that is an excellent book. It is an introduction to category theory that claims that only a high school background is necessary so, as most of us know, that means if you have a good solid background in mathematics then it is a highly readable introduction to category theory.